# LAMP vs MAMP for web development

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mamp, lamp

Im curious, between LAMP and MAMP, which of the two is the best platform to do web development in? I develop majority of my sites on a MAMP dev platform but I always see job postings looking for developers that are familiar with LAMP. Any reason why?

Comment: Thanks for answering but I already know that one operates in Linux and the other in OSX, I'm curious for why companies prefer one over the other if they both can achieve the same thing. @adeneo

Comment: Linux is free. OSX costs money like Windows. So unless you've just got a bunch of old Macs lying around, you'd probably want to go with Linux.

Comment: originally its LAMP not MAMP. Linux is a default platform and a lot more robust. In addition, most apps that are in prod are hosted in Linux. I'd go with LAMP. MAMP is just you can develop on a mac.

Comment: Rodger that, going to take a further look into Ubuntu and compare it to OSX. Thanks much guys! Truly appreciate it.

Comment: MAMP is _very_ similar to LAMP, both are Unix-like operating systems. WAMP is based on Windows, which is a very different beast. It is possible to write your code to run on all three, but in practice unless it has to, just develop against the one you plan to use. MAMP is indeed used by some firms [as a hosting option - Mac Minis](https://www.mythic-beasts.com/order/macmini)! However, Linux is much more popular, and is probably cheaper, since there are usually no licensing fees.

Answer (score 1):

Job postings for LAMP setup are simply because most hosting is linux-based, for varying reasons but above all because it's free. For development, there isn't much difference aside from the selection of editors you can use, and which OS the developer is more comfortable with.